# Pricing for customer portal and Partner portal users

Tags: customer-portal, partner-portal

I have a requirement such that there are lot of portal users.  For this purpose I need to know the pricing details of customer portal and partner portal user licences.. I checked the below link but it does not show any pricing for portal users..

http://www.salesforce.com/in/crm/editions-pricing-communities.jsp

Any where it is documented?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: This is not a topic suited to SF.SE. Contact your Account Rep for pricing info.

Answer (score 2):

Contact your client's AE to get actual pricing... nobody here can give you that!

Three types:

1. Named User Licenses - you pay per license
2. Number of Logins - you pay for an amount of logins your Clients can
   use each month
3. A combination.  You can do both of the above in a different assortment so you can give users that hardly login a 'number of logins' license and others a 'named user' license that are your heavy users.